# Forcing mobs to target players in MobArena regardless of range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Title says it all. I have a fortress-like arena, and I have the mobs spawning outside of the walls. However, the mobs simply stand there and don't attack because they are too far away, making them easy pickings for archers. Is there a workaround for this, or do I need to rethink my design?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I'm using the plugin MobArena to control my arena, thus probably limiting the customisation with the mobs.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the follow range of mobs higher. Assuming you want to summon a zombie:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:100.0}]}
```

This zombie will follow you up to 100 blocks far.

(You can also let mobs directly target specific players or entities, but for that you would need to know their UUID, so it would only ever work for one player in the world.)

Comment: How would I implement this into a MobArena config though? I forgot to add that I'm using the plugin

Comment: I don't really know what that is. But if the zombies already exist, you can use entitydata to modify all zombies (that would have to be on a clock): /entitydata @e[type=zombie] {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:100.0}]}

Answer (score 1):

If you are spawning in the mobs individually, then as Fabian said:

> Assuming you want to summon a zombie:
>
> `/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:100.0}]}`
>
> This zombie will follow you up to 100 blocks far.

However if you want to customise this for every mob, especially if used in a plugin like MobArena, do this:

`/entitydata @e[type=Zombie,r=150] {Attributes:[{Name:generic.followRange,Base:150}]}`

Change Zombie to whatever mobs you want